# Scanner available only with sudo

Tags: debian, sudo, scanner

I have an *Epson ET-2756* printer. I'm able to print easily with it, but it took me a long time to understand why under *Debian 10* my computer wasn't able to detect its scanner part.

Eventually, I've found why : the `scanimage` command (and then `epsonscan2` specifically installed for the printer) are only able to detect its scanner provided they are ran with a `sudo`.

I wonder why... And especially, I would like to remove this prerequisite.
How may I remove the need of a `sudo` to perform a scan?

---

Experience suggested by cas, below :

```bsh
# I look already registered as a scanner group member
cat /etc/group | grep scanner
scanner:x:117:saned,lebihan

# But this command fails:
scanimage --format=png >/tmp/test.png
scanimage: no SANE devices found

# While this one succeeds:
sudo scanimage --format=png >/tmp/test.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to the `scanner` group.  i.e.

```
sudo addgroup yourusername scanner
```

Next time you login, your uid will be able to use the scanner.

Alternatively, the `libpam-systemd` package can ensure that the correct permissions are set when a user logs in, **if** there are appropriate `udev` rules to do so.  It's easier to just add yourself to the scanner group, though.

See the following on the Debian Wiki:

- [SystemGroups #Groups without an associated user](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups#Groups_without_an_associated_user)
- [Scanner #Permissions](https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner#Permissions)

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question, after having checked that I was in the `scanner` group: I was in already.

Comment: OK, you probably need to look at the bug report mentioned in the Scanner#Permissions link.  It's mostly about problems with Epson scanners, and has some udev rules that apparently fix the problem (i haven't looked closely at the problem - my scanner is an HP3030 and works fine with just me in group scanner)

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.OR, reconnect and `ls -lrt /dev | tail`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: That sounds scary. What if the group is `disk` (just imagining here) - better check before adding a user to a system group. Ideally one would create a `udev` rule and give the device to the `users` group.

Comment: @Ned64 What's "scary"? Do you know about the owner/group/world permission scheme? The `man` command? Blindly following recipes without figuring out what they do is scary.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.